# SQL server - how to find Hexadecimal character in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to search hexadecimal characters from a SQL Server table? Actually I tried like below but it is searching all zeroes in the field.

```
select Email,* 
from address 
where CHARINDEX(convert(varchar, Ascii(0x00)), Email) > 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to find? What would be a match, what wouldn't?

Answer (score 45):

I had a similar problem where a hexadecimal character was crashing a query. This is what I did to find it.

```
select Email
from address
where Email like '%' + CHAR(0x00) +'%'
```

Now to stop the bad data getting in in the first place...

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for a similar problem I was having (illegal XML characters).