# Special characters in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm running into an error exporting my database data into an excel spreadsheet:

```
""\v', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character.
```

It looks like this is the symbol for male (♂️), and I'm not even seeing this in my database query. Is there a way to search for this hexadecimal value within an existing query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744334/the-quest-for-0x0b and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794487/sql-server-how-to-find-hexadecimal-character-in-a-table might help with the scan.

Comment: @TEEKAY The second link was what I needed! I had narrowed my error down to 15 rows, then when I ran the query, it selected 6 rows. Found my culprit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII 0x0B is a vertical. To find values containing the character, use `CHAR` and `LIKE`:

```
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%' + CHAR(11) + '%'
```

Comment: If it is 0B (zero Beta)  then... WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%' + CHAR(11) + '%

Comment: It's actually 0x0B and not 0x08, but the general query is definitely what I needed. Was able to use CHAR(0x0B) like a charm.

Comment: @LOL.NO., time to clean my glasses. I updated my answer.